# Polarization operators and the action of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$

Tags: invariant-theory, algebraic-combinatorics

(**Also in Mathematics stack Exchange:** https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2528216/polarization-operators-identity-and-gl-ell-mathbbr)

Let $X$ be a matrix of variables $x_{ij}$ of size $\ell\times n$:
\begin{equation*}
X=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} x_{11}&x_{12} &\dots & x_{1n}\\
x_{21}&x_{22} &\dots & x_{2n}\\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{\ell 1}&x_{\ell 2} &\dots & x_{\ell n}\\\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
The ring $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}=\mathbb{R}[X]$ of polynomials in $\ell$ sets of $n$ variables is defined as the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space generated by the monomials:
$$X^{A}=\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{n}x_{ij}^{a_{ij}}$$
The multidegree of a monomial in this ring is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\deg\left(X^{A}\right):=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{1j},\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{2j},\dots,\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{\ell j}\right)
\end{equation*}
So an element $f\in\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ have the form
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle{f(X)=\sum_{A\in\mathbb{N}^{\ell\times n}}f_{A}X^{A}}
\end{equation*}
The **multidegree** of $f$ is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\deg\left(f(X)\right):={\max}_{{\rm grlex}}\left\{\deg\left(X^{A}\right):\ f_{A}\neq 0\right\}.
\end{equation*}
where the maximum is taken w.r.t. the **graded lexicographic order** in $\mathbb{N}^{\ell}$. So the ring $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is $\mathbb{N}^{\ell}$ graded.

Let $Q$ be the following diagonal matrix:
\begin{equation*}
Q=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
q_1&0&\dots&0\\
0&q_2&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\dots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&q_{\ell}\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
A polynomial $f(X)\in\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is said to be **homogeneous of multidegree ${\bf d}$** if the following condition holds:
\begin{equation*}
f(QX)={\bf q}^{\bf d}f(X).
\end{equation*}
where ${\bf q}=(q_1,\dots,q_{\ell})$, ${\bf d}=(d_1,\dots,d_{\ell})$ , ${\bf q}^{\bf d}=q_1^{d_1}\dots q_{\ell}^{d_{\ell}}$. It's well known that

> For a matrix of variables $Y=(y_{{ij}})$ of size $\ell\times n$ and $f\in\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ an homogeneous polynomial of multidegree ${\bf d}$, then for every matrix $M$ of size $\ell\times\ell$ we have
> \begin{equation*}
> f(MX)=\sum_{\big\{K\in\mathbb{N}^{\ell\times\ell}:\ \big\vert{K}\big\vert={\bf d}\big\}}
> \frac{M^{K}}{K!}\,\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{\ell}P_{j,i}^{k_{ij}}
> \big(f(Y)\big),
> \end{equation*}
> where $$K!:=\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{\ell}k_{ij}!}$$
> $$\displaystyle{M^{K}=\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{\ell}m_{i,j}^{k_{ij}}}$$
> and the **polarization operator** $P_{ik}$ is given by
> $$P_{i,k}:=\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{ij}\frac{\partial\ }{\partial y_{kj}}}.$$

The notation $\ \big\vert{K}\big\vert={\bf d}$ represents the set of all squares matrices $K$ of order $\ell$ such that $\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{ij}=d_{i}}$, for all $i$ such that $1\leq i\leq\ell$.

> **My question:** Reading Claudio Procesi book I saw that the ring $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is closed under polarization operators $P_{ik}$ if and only if is closed under the action of the general linear group $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$. Using the formula for $f(MX)$ above I can understand why geing closed under the $P_{ik}$ implies that $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is closed under the right side action of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$. But, how to find the matrices $M$ to show the reciprocal of this result.

***An example is the following :***

Let $f({\bf y}_1,{\bf y}_2)=y_{_{11}}y_{_{21}}+y_{_{12}}y_{_{22}}$. This  polynomial $f({\bf y}_1,{\bf y}_2)\in\mathcal{R}_{2}^{(2)}(Y)$ is homogeneous of multidegree $(1,1)$ in the matrix variable $Y$ bellow:

\begin{equation*}
Y:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
y_{_{11}}&y_{_{12}}\\
y_{_{21}}&y_{_{22}}
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}

We write the rows of $X$ as ${\bf x}_1=(x_{_{11}},x_{_{12}})$ et ${\bf x}_2=(x_{_{21}},x_{_{22}})$ and the same for $Y$.

Let $M$  be the following matrix:
\begin{equation*}
M:=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
m_{_{11}}&m_{_{12}}\\
m_{_{21}}&m_{_{22}}
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
Notice that $f(Y)=f({\bf y}_1,{\bf y}_2)=f(y_{_{11}},y_{_{12}};y_{_{21}},y_{_{22}})=y_{_{11}}y_{_{21}}+y_{_{12}}y_{_{22}}$, then
\begin{align*}
&f\left(MX\right)=f\left(\left(\begin{array}{cc}
m_{_{11}}&m_{_{12}}\\
m_{_{21}}&m_{_{22}}
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c} {\bf x}_1\\{\bf x}_2 \end{array}\right)\right)
=f\big(m_{_{11}}{\bf x}_1+m_{_{12}}{\bf x}_2\,;\,m_{_{21}}{\bf x}_1+m_{_{22}}{\bf x}_2\big)\\
&=f\big(m_{_{11}}x_{_{11}}+m_{_{12}}x_{_{21}},m_{_{11}}x_{_{12}}+m_{_{12}}x_{_{22}}\,;\,m_{_{21}}x_{_{11}}+m_{_{22}}x_{_{21}},m_{_{21}}x_{_{12}}+m_{_{22}}x_{_{22}}\big)\\
&=\big(m_{_{11}}x_{_{11}}+m_{_{12}}x_{_{21}}\big)\big(m_{_{21}}x_{_{11}}+m_{_{22}}x_{_{21}}\big)+\big(m_{_{11}}x_{_{12}}+m_{_{12}}x_{_{22}}\big)\big(m_{_{21}}x_{_{12}}+m_{_{22}}x_{_{22}}\big)\\
&=m_{_{11}}m_{_{21}}x_{_{11}}^{2}+m_{_{11}}m_{_{21}}x_{_{12}}^{2}
+m_{_{11}}m_{_{22}}x_{_{11}}x_{_{21}}+m_{_{11}}m_{_{22}}x_{_{12}}x_{_{22}}
+m_{_{12}}m_{_{21}}x_{_{11}}x_{_{21}}\\
&+m_{_{12}}m_{_{21}}x_{_{12}}x_{_{22}}+m_{_{12}}m_{_{22}}x_{_{21}}^{2}+m_{_{12}}m_{_{22}}x_{_{22}}^{2}.\\
&=m_{_{21}}m_{_{12}} \left( x_{_{11}}x_{_{21}}+x_{_{12}}x_{_{22}}
 \right) +m_{_{11}}m_{_{22}} \left( x_{_{11}}x_{_{21}}+x_{_{12}}x_{_{22}} \right)+m_{_{11}}m_{_{21}} \left( x_{_{11}}^{2}+x_{_{12}}^{2} \right) +m_{_{12}}m_{_{22}} \left( x_{_{21}}^{2}+x_{_{22}}^{2}
 \right)\\
&=m_{_{21}}m_{_{12}}P_{1,2}P_{2,1}(f(Y))+m_{_{11}}m_{_{22}}P_{11}P_{22}(f(Y))
+m_{_{11}}m_{_{21}}P_{12}P_{11}(f(Y))+m_{_{12}}m_{_{22}}P_{21}P_{22}(f(Y)).
\end{align*}

Thank for any hint on this.

Comment: There must be a typo in the formula for $P_{i,k}$: the variable $y_{kj}$ should be $x_{kj}$.

Comment: This seems rather similar to your question on math.SE: [Polarization Operators identity and $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2528216).

Comment: @FriedrichKnop: Thank you for the answer, this give me a good idea how to continue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have the time to work out precisely how to derive Procesi's claim from the formula for $f(MX)$ but probably it is a cute exercise along the following lines: let $E_{k,i}$ be the elementary matrix whose $(k,i)$-entry equals $1$ and all other entries are $0$. Now calculate $f(MX)$ for $M={\bf1}_\ell+tE_{k,i}$ and take the derivative with respect to $t$ at $t=0$. This should be $P_{i,k}f(X)$ from which the claim follows.

But much more directly, Procesi's claim follows simply from the fact the $P_{i,k}$ generate the action of the Lie algebra ${\rm Lie}\, GL_\ell(\mathbb R)$. Since $GL_\ell(\mathbb R)$ is connected (as an algebraic group!) and the ground field $\mathbb R$ is of characteristic zero, a subspace is $GL_\ell(\mathbb R)$-closed iff it is closed for the action of its Lie algebra.